# PCA - Plotting individual distance to principal component

Tags: r, pca

I am doing a PCA analysis with the CRAN iris dataset. I wonder how I can create the following plot:
 
I want to select the first principal component and for this component I want to plot the distance for each individual from this component. Any hint would be much appreciated!

The commands for PCA are the following:

```
data(iris)
log.ir <- log(iris[,1:4])
ir.species <- iris[,5]
ir.pca <- prcomp(log.ir, center=TRUE, scale. = TRUE)
ir.pca
```

Cheers!

Comment: getting the principle components out of the variable `ir.pca` is not hard: just do- `PCs=ir.pca$x ;head(PCs)` then you could do: `plot(PCs[,1],PCs[,2],col=ir.species)`- the separation of the different species will show up this way. However I'm a bit confused about what you mean by the 'distance' between the different species as I'm inexperienced with PCA.. However you could probably get what you want from the `PCs` variable made above.

Comment: After some resarch, I am looking for a 1D Score Plot command in R.

Comment: i think just plotting the first principle component is what your looking for: `plot(PCs[,1],col=ir.species)` ,again i'm not an expert... nothing comes up on '1D score plot' when I google it other than that the 'score' is just the transformation that PCA does to the data. So you can just plot the first component and colour the points according to the species as I've shown you above. You may also investigate the command `strip_chart`.

Comment: Thanks! That solves my issue!

Comment: no problem- could you upvote my comment? I'd appreciate it, thanks